# styling angular 7 material icon row

Tags: angular, angular-material

I'm trying to style angular 7 material. The field in particular I'm fighting with is icon-form-field. I want to have an icon, label then either slider or radiobutton as the input for the field. But I can't figure out how to get the 3 items to line up in the veritcal center of the icon-form-field, and I can't get the icon-form-field to only take 50% of the horizontal width of the div (I want to have two fields on the same line). Also, how to you decide when to use the scss file in the component and when to use the global styles.scss file?

Here's a screenshot of what I have:
[image]

Here is the html:

```
    <div layout="row" fxFlex>
       <div class="col-sm-2" flex="50" style="border: 1px solid">
         <h2>General</h2>
         <div class="icon-form-field" fxFlexRow style="border: 1px solid;">
             <mat-icon color="accent">reorder</mat-icon>
             <label class="slider-label" style="align-self: center">Sticky Header</label>
             <mat-slide-toggle
               [checked]="settings.stickyHeader"
               (change)="onStickyHeaderToggle($event)">
             </mat-slide-toggle>
         </div>
       </div>
     </div>
```

and the css I've tried so far (this is in the component.scss):

```
.mat-icon {
  border: solid 1px black;
}
```

and in the styles.scss:

```
.slider-label {
  margin: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  border: solid 1px black;
}
```

Any and all hints/ideas are appreciated!

Thanks.....

Comment: Please have a look at this: https://codepen.io/zavoloklom/pen/yaozl maybe It'll help. also try using line height for the slider label..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What version of Flex Layout are you using? It seems you are not using it properly.

> Have a look at
>   [this](https://stackblitz.com/edit/am-all-imports-ml5azr?file=app%2Fapp.component.html)
>   working stackblitz. I have copied the main `div` just to showcase that two of them fit on the same row.

I cleaned up the Flex Layout stuff, all you really need is:

```
<div fxLayout="row">
  <div fxFlex="50">
  </div>
</div>
```

And then you just need to vertically align the items (icon, label, slider) inside your `div`. You can do this with CSS:

```
.vertical-align {
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

And just apply to class to the above mentioned elements.